# A small confusion regarding unrestricted integral and integral over a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a very simple question but it's confusing me a bit nonetheless.

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f\geq0$ is a measurable function. Let $A=\{\omega\in \Omega:f(\omega)>0\}$ and suppose $\mu(A^c)=0$.

Suppose $g:\Omega\to\mathbb R_+$ is defined by $g(\omega)=1/f(\omega)$ if $\omega\in A$ and $1$ otherwise. So note I can write $g=\mathbb I_A/f +\mathbb I_{A^c}$.

Then can I say that $ \int gd\mu=\int (1/f) d\mu$ considering $\mu(A^c)=0$? I feel the answer is yes, but I just want to clarify that whatever I do in $\int (1/f)d\mu$ will work even when $f=0$.

Comment: Also, is the representation $g=\mathbb I_A/f+\mathbb I_{A^c}$ well-defined? What happens when $f(\omega)=0$? Then will we get 0/0 form or will the indicator dominate?

Comment: Measure theory usually works in the so-called 'extended reals'. I think $\frac{1}{0}$ is usually defined to be $+\infty$, and $0\cdot(+\infty)$ is defined to be $0$. Therefore, no matter what [extended real]-valued measurable function $g$ you're considering, it is always true that $\int_E g d\mu = 0$ if $\mu(E) = 0$ (since the integral is at most $\mu(E)\cdot (+\infty)$). Therefore, in your question, $\int gd\mu = \int (1/f)d\mu$ is valid. As to the last sentence of your question, if you work in the extended reals (which you kinda need to, if you want to talk about $1/0$), then

Comment: 'whatever [you] do in $\int (1/f)d\mu$' will indeed work when $f=0$. In response to your comment, if we evaluate $\mathbb{I}_A \frac{1}{f}$ at some $\omega$ with $\omega \not \in A$ and $f(\omega) = 0$, then we are evaluating $0\cdot (+\infty)$, which is $0$.

Comment: Working in the extended reals with the convention that $0\cdot (+\infty) = 0$ allows you to, for all intents and purposes, always 'ignore' sets of measure $0$; i.e., they never affect anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments!